odoo17 multi Many2Many meme model
comment creer deux champs achteur et vendeur many2many, sur meme model societe
les acheteurs et les vendeurs sont automatiquement renseignés dans les champs contacts,
TypeError: Many2many fields societe.dossier.vendeur_ids and societe.dossier.achteur_ids use the same table and columns

j ai utiliser les codes sur les deux fichiers

  class societeDossiere(models.Model):
    _name = "societe.dossier"
                
    numdossier = fields.Char()
    dateDossier = fields.Date()
                
    achteur_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='societe.contact', string='achteur')
        vendeur_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='societe.contact', string='vendeur')

